# Function that takes a string and returns an array with the length of each word added to each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I tried split() to make an array out of it then map() to add numbers next to the strings.

```
function nameLength(str) {
    const words = str.split(" ");
    return words.map(str => $(words) $(words.length));
}

console.log(nameLength("hawaii pizza"));

was expecting:

[ 'hawaii 6', 'pizza 5' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the wrong string. also your syntax is also wrong
just try this

```js
function nameLength(str) {
    const words = str.split(" ");
    return words.map(str => `${str} ${str.length}`);
}

function nameWithIndex(str){
  const words = str.split(" ");
  return words.map((string, index) => `${index}. ${string}`);
}

console.log(nameLength("hawaii pizza"));
console.log(nameWithIndex("hawaii pizza"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply it worked.

Is there also a way the puts the numbers in front of the items, so it represents its position in the list?
like this: ["1. Hawaii Pizza", "2. Diablo Pizza"]

Comment: yes sure, I have updated the snippet in the answer above. You can check that